# ListView Validation not happenning on ItemInserting

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a `Listview` with a small validation on `ItemInserting`.

The problem is that it isn't working.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
      <td>
          <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
          <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
      </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="ProgrammeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Programme") %>' />
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="ProgrammeTextBox" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="OutcomeCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Outcome") %>' />
      </td>
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void ListView1_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
   {
        CheckBox chk = e.Item.FindControl("OutcomeCheckBox") as CheckBox;
        RequiredFieldValidator RFV1 = e.Item.FindControl("RequiredFieldValidator1") as RequiredFieldValidator;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            RFV1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            RFV1.Enabled = false;
        } 
    }
}
```

The `ListView1_ItemInserting` isn't applying the Required Field Validator when the checkbox is checked.

Any ideas???
I cant work out why this is not firing.

Comment: I can't see any `ListView` mentioned in your code?

Comment: Hi KJSR ?? What do you mean? I have pasted in the Insert section of the Listview code...

Comment: Ok sorry didn't realise `InsertItemTemplate` is used inside `ListView`.